# Rails association with same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Article and model User. In users, there will be one creator of the article and many readers. How do I link these together? 
I was thinking:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_one created_by, through: :user (????)
end



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

Comment: Why it has `has_and_belongs_to_many` association with users?

Comment: And also why your `User` model has `has_many :articles` while your `Article` model having `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`?

Comment: Because I want the user to have many articles and one article can be owned by many users

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_one created_by_user,:class_name => 'User'

end
```

If you want to specify a `custom foreign_key`(which is useful in these cases),you can specify a `foreign_key` option

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :users
has_one created_by_user,:class_name => 'User',:foreign_key =>'your_custom_fkey'

end
```